# How can i test vectors/arrays of different sizes without using functions? (c++)

Tags: c++, c++14

I need help testing arrays of different sizes. In this case they are char vectors.

The whole purpose of this is so that I can print the difference of each array (like the char that is in one array and not the other).

```
#include "SetProj.h"

using namespace std;

Set::Set(){

    Big = 0;
    Small = 0;

}

Set::Set(int x, int y, vector<char> A, vector<char> B) {

    Big = x;
    Small = y;
    SetA = A;
    SetB = B;

}

void Set::validate(vector<char> Tester) {


    for (int i = 0; i < Tester.size(); i++) {

        if ((Tester[i] >= 'a' && Tester[i] <= 'z') || (Tester[i] >= 'A' && Tester[i] <= 'Z')) {

            cout << Tester[i] << " ";
        }

        else {
            Tester.erase(Tester.begin() + i);
        }
    }

    if (SetA.size() >= SetB.size()) {

        Big = SetA.size();
        Small = SetB.size();

    }

    else {
        Big = SetB.size();
        Small = SetA.size();
        
    }

}

void Set::fillSetA(){

    char sent = ';';
    char Input;

    cout << "Hello, welcome to set thingy. please fill set. if you want a null set, just quit.(';' to quit)" << endl;
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin >> Input;

    while (Input != sent) {

        SetA.push_back(Input);

        cout << "Enter: ";
        cin >> Input;
    }

    validate(SetA);
    cout << endl;
}

void Set::fillSetB() {

    char sent = ';';
    char Input;

    cout << "Hello, welcome to set thingy. please fill set. if you want a null set, just quit.(';' to quit)" << endl;
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin >> Input;

    while (Input != sent) {

        SetB.push_back(Input);
        
        cout << "Enter: ";
        cin >> Input;
    }

    validate(SetB);
    cout << endl;
}

void Set::difference() {

    //char n1;
    vector<char> n1;
    bool match = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < SetA.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SetB.size(); j++) {
            if (SetA[i] == SetB[j]) {
                match = true;
                break;
                //cout << SetA[i] << " ";
            }
            /*else {
                n1.insert(n1.begin(), SetA[i]);//[i] = SetA[i];

            }*/
        }
        if (!match) {

            n1.push_back(SetA[i]);
        }
    }

    cout << "A-B= {";

    for (int i = 0; i < n1.size(); i++) {

        cout << n1[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;

    /*

    cout << "B-A= {";

    for (int i = 0; i < Small; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Big; j++) {
            if (SetB[i] == SetA[j]) {

                n1 = SetB[i];
            }
            else {

                cout << SetB[i] << " ";
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
    */
}
```

I've tried multiple times, but the issue is that I just get doubles of everything in one vector.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line. You'll find something interesting about `match` when you get to the double `for` loop.

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier if you sorted the vectors and use `std::set_difference`, instead of what you're doing now to determine the differences.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie we aren't allowed to use std::set_difference—only data structs and algorithms.

Comment: `std::set_difference` and `std::sort` are in the `<algorithm>` header -- they are not containers.

Comment: `set_difference` is an algorithm. In fact, an implementation is given [on the wiki](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: Also this: `if ((Tester[i] >= 'a' && Tester[i] <= 'z') || (Tester[i] >= 'A' && Tester[i] <= 'Z'))` is not the way to test if a character is alphabetic.  The correct way is to use `std::isalpha()`.  What if the character is foreign, but a valid alphabetic character?  Your test will miss it.  What if the code you have is run on a system where the characters are not contiguous in the collating sequence?  Again, your code would miss it.  The system knows what is an alphabetic character -- that's why `std::isalpha` exists.

Comment: `Tester.erase(Tester.begin() + i);` is going to create confusing results when combined with the `i++` in the `for` loop. Again, you would have noticed this in a debugger.

Comment: I highly recommend passing your vectors by reference or `const` reference if the vector is not modified.  Otherwise the compiler will make a copy of the vector before passing it to the function.

Comment: Be aware that there is a `std::set` in the `std::namespace`.  When `using namespace std;`, you bring the `std::set` into the global namespace, which may cause conflicts.